# NSMutableArray and alloc

Tags: ios, memory-management, nsmutablearray

I have a function that will fill an array which is visible in all functions of MainViewController.

So I have:

```
@implementation MainViewController
 NSMutableArray *annotations;
```

and the allocation happens in the function:

```
annotation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

but this function is will executed more than 1 times.
Each time that the function is executed I want the data on the array to be deleted. 
So this one is working but is it correct? Should I alloc it out of the function and set the function to remove all object before entering the new data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't that clear but as far is I can understand you're just asking if calling

`annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` in your function is ok?

In that case it is a duplicate of [this question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476920/ios-arc-nsmutablearray-do-i-need-to-removeallobjects-before-alloc-new-memory-for?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Sorry my bad. I searched before asking but I didn't notice it.